# VB6 Check if File that will be Overwritten is Open

Tags: vba, excel, vb6, grid, export-to-excel

This code overwrite existing file if not open, but not if it's open, but I don't have any validation if file is open or not, so what happens is that it still saying "Export Success" even it did not overwrite because file is open at the moment.

```
 On Error GoTo errtrap

cd.CancelError = True
cd.Filter = "*.xls|*.xls"
cd.FileName = gReportTitle & " " & Format(Now, "mmddyyyy")
cd.ShowSave
If FileExists(cd.FileName) Then
        If fMessageBox("", "Overwrite File?", "Yes", "No", 0, 1, True) = 1 Then
            Grid1.ExportToExcel cd.FileName, True, True
            MsgBox ("Export Success!")
        Else
            Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
         Grid1.ExportToExcel cd.FileName, True, True

End If
 Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault

   errtrap:
   Screen.MousePointer = vbDefault
```

Comment: Could you please add more details? Do you want to know if the file is open or not?

Answer (score 1):

The below code will check if the file is open or not

```
Sub TestFileOpened()

Dim wb As Workbook

 Dim filename As String

 filename = "C:\Documents and Settings\vn\Desktop\test.xlsx"
    ' Test to see if the file is open.
    If IsFileOpen(filename) Then
        ' Display a message stating the file in use.
        MsgBox "File already in use!"

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename)


'wb.Close

        '
        ' Add code here to handle case where file is open by another
        ' user.
        '
    Else
        ' Display a message stating the file is not in use.
        MsgBox "File not in use!"
        ' Open the file in Microsoft Excel.
 Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename)

        '
        ' Add code here to handle case where file is NOT open by another
        ' user.
        '
    End If

End Sub

' This function checks to see if a file is open or not. If the file is
' already open, it returns True. If the file is not open, it returns
' False. Otherwise, a run-time error occurs because there is
' some other problem accessing the file.

Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
```